# Prolog Domain of activity

Tags: prolog

I have found a Prolog program and read about AI programming a little. My program is :

```
causes(measles, spots).
causes(mumps, swollen_glands).

known(spots).

diagnosis(Symptom,Disease) :-
    causes(Disease,Symptom),
    known(Symptom).
```

and it's file name is :

> ex.pl

when i run this command on Linux :

> swipl ex.pl

I get this prompt

> ?-

My question is how can I ask a question from it beside of getting true or false answers ? Like "what is the name of the disease causes spots?" Or what happen when I delete the line of:

```
known(spots).
```

Or is there is any interesting question can I ask it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer to "what is the name of the disease causes spots?" (notice the capital in `Disease`):

```
?- causes(Disease, spots).
Disease = measles.
```

Longer answer: Prolog is a logic programming language. This means that you program code is **universally quantified**. For example, the following code states "All diseases that cause a known symptom have that symptom as a diagnosis".

```
diagnosis(Symptom,Disease) :-
  causes(Disease,Symptom),
  known(Symptom).
```

Your queries in the top-level are **existentially quantified**. For example `causes(Disease, spots)` asks "Is there a disease that causes spots?".

The following are also universally quantified (since they belong to the program code). But since they contain no variables to quantify over they are facts.

```
causes(measles, spots).
causes(mumps, swollen_glands).
known(spots).
```

PS: Notice that your code does not state what a disease and a symptom is. This is only apparent from your choice of variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,How could i state what a disease and a symptom is?

Comment: @user38322 "Being a disease" and "being a symptom" are properties. They are denoted by unary predicates. In code: `disease(measles).` and `symptom(spots).`